# Unreal engine 4 Не удается открыть источник

Tags: unreal-engine-4

При долгой работе возникает множество ошибок подобного рода:

Ошибка (активно)    E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMCriticalSection.h" Trentor C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\CriticalSection.h

Ошибка (активно)    E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM/UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORMPlatformCompilerPreSetup.h"    Trentor C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.25\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\HAL\Platform.h    81

Из-за этого не работает IntelliSense.

Пробовал удалить папку Intermediate, но это не помогло.

Как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Exactly the same, i recently installed UE4.25 and VS2019 and ive got same 13357 errors !
Did you find the solution ?